# iPhone AVFoundation image EXIF orientation

Tags: iphone, exif, avfoundation

I'm using AVFoundation to control the camera in my app and it's working perfectly... up til now.

The images are saved into the library with no problems and all look perfect but when I then upload them to Facebook they're the wrong way round!

This happens whether I upload them from within my app or from the Facebook app on my iPhone.

I have tried setting the EXIF data using the CMSetAttachment method but this just makes it even worse.  It then displays incorrectly on the phone and on Facebook.

Has anyone found any way of getting this to work properly?

Thanks

Comment: OK, I just did a test and uploaded 4 photos with exif data (up, down, left and right) and 4 without exif data.  On Facebook it made no difference whatsoever but on my phone the exif data meant they displayed incorrectly.

Answer (score -2):

It is very simple.

**Facebook/Windows.. has it wrong!**

Mac / Iphone do interogate the exif on every picture and act accordingly.

Windows machines "sometimes" (in fact always) ignore exifs when previewing a photo.

In order to check that what I am saying is correct, do the following:

Try transfering the "faulty" picture from a MAC OS / Iphone OS to a WINDOWS OS using any messenger utility which has file transfer capability.

Hit preview in both operating systems.

Watch Windows make a fool of itself.

If you understand this.. you can make some workarounds.. up to a certain level.. as to try and rotate the picture accordingly before upload.

Good luck.

Windows sucks!

Comment: So the only way round then would be to manually rotate the photos before uploading them to Facebook?  I suppose I could do this on the phone but it's expensive work!  Thanks!